# Amazon RDS and Managing my own database

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services

We have been using a company to manage our database cluster on Amazon, and after a 5 year relationship, I've lost complete confidence in them.

A couple of months ago, we began to experience timeouts on Heroku which we were told was due to too much being written to the logs consuming the full 100 GBs of space.  I was instructed to delete data (removing 10GB from the original 36GB over two databases), then later told that even deleting data was not effectively reclaiming the space.

We moved last week to an M1.small instance on Amazon, and after two hours, we totally shut down. After an hour, they finally moved us to an M1.xlarge instance. They wrote:

```
...realtime monitoring of the affected unit showed very high i/o wait 
times, indicating that the unit was 'disk bound', that is, the delay 
was caused by reads that had to go to disk instead of being found in 
the memory cache
```

When I look at the configuration info on M1, it seems surprising they chose an option that is more expensive and for which EBS is an addon. The M4 choice is the less expensive, of the newer generation and includes EBS at no additional charge. Am I correct in this?

Since I do not have command line access, I'm fully reliant on reaching the database admins when I have a problem. This has resulted in us being down for 15 minutes at a time while I awaited a response.

Perhaps I am naive, but it seems that the database -- when on the proper environment, needs little attention, and that most issues can be solved with my own command line access. I have been programming for two decades and obviously managing my own database for years, but I am not a database admin. Can you tell me the pitfalls of managing my own database that I may be unaware of?

I feel a mistake was made to not properly assess our needs, and then move us to a small instance only to realize they had to scale up almost immediately. What criteria should I analyze to determine the appropriate database size and choice on Amazon?

Any other information you can offer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinning up new M1 instances these days is crazy. You are correct that you should be taking advantage of the latest instance classes. I'm guessing that they have your database running in an EC2 Classic environment, instead of a more modern VPC environment, which is preventing the use of newer AWS features.

What type of database engine are you using? Why aren't you using Amazon's RDS service?

Comment: We have a mix of InnoDB and MyISam tables. Honestly, I thought we were taking advantage of Amazon's RDS service and only learned this morning that we were using M1. Do you have suggestions for moving to InnoDB or assessing the criteria for selecting the proper instance?

Comment: Since you are disk bound, it sounds like you need an EBS optimized instance type, and beyond that you just need to provision an EBS volume with the correct IOPS. Determining exactly what size instance and what IOPS volume you need usually comes down to looking at your CloudWatch metrics to understand your historical CPU and IOPS usage to determine what you need to support.

As a side note, I would definitely recommend looking into a migration to AWS Aurora.

Comment: Ask them to take iostat readings and tell you the average steal times.  These are all shared and if the infrastructure is being overwhelmed, that will usually show overallocations.  Also, unless the MyISAM tables are used for semaphores or static data, you are better off going to InnoDB.